# Why is there a problem with my JDK even though I installed it with Unity?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, android-build

#### JDK Problems

I am making a mobile game in Unity 2022.2.2f1 and every time I open the editor, or press play it shows the error:
"Unable to find java in the system path. This tool is required to process Android libraries. Please configure your JDK location under the 'Unity Preferences > External Tools' menu."

[image: The error that pops up]

When I go to the External Tools menu there are no errors or warnings.

[image: The External Tools menu]

I don't know why it is doing this. I don't know if it is because of something I did, or if it is a Unity problem, or something else.

I tried to uncheck the boxes that said installed with Unity and selected the paths manually.

I tried to reinstall the editor with the modules.

I tried uninstalling all the editors I had and only reinstalling this one (2022.2.2f1).

Answer (score 0):

You should try these steps:

1. Update Unity hub to latest version.
2. Uninstall Unity.
3. Restart your PC.
4. Re-install unity without unity hub (get the file from the archive directory at https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive ).
5. Point the unity hub to your download path.

This has worked for me before so hopefully it works for you as well.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work.

Comment: that's unfortunate @EthanTuininga ... please share whatever ends up working

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: ensure the **bin** folder is mentioned in the PATH Environment Variables.

If you copy the path verify that it exists (via windows explorer), then you need to make sure PATH variable knows about it.

- Copy the path to the bin folder. In my case it was: `C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.1.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\`
- [image]
- Open the Windows Start Menu, search for "Environment Variables," and select "Edit the system environment variables."
- In the System Properties window that appears, click the "Environment Variables" button.
- Under the "System variables" section, find and select the "Path" variable, then click "Edit."
- In the Edit Environment Variable window, click "New" and paste the copied path.
- Click "OK" to close all of the windows.

After updating the PATH, you'll need to restart any command prompts or possibly even your IDE for the change to take effect. You can test whether it's been successfully added by opening a new command prompt and running `java -version`. If it shows the Java version, then it's in the PATH correctly.

Then restart unity, visual studio, unity hub, close any command prompt if you had it open.